# Button click counter for login user

Tags: functions, database, forms

I am new with wordpress and trying to create button counter also saving click into database. This form is only for wordpress login users.

Function.php

```
function getcount($userID){         
    $click_key = 'click_count';
    $count = get_user_meta($userID, $click_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_user_meta($userID, $click_key);
        add_user_meta($userID, $click_key, '0');
        return "0 click";
    }
    return $count.'click';
}
function setcount($userID){
    $click_key = 'click_count';
    $count = get_user_meta($userID, $click_key, true);
    $count++;
    update_user_meta($userID, $click_key, $count);
}
```

HTML:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
        setcount($userID);
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('home')?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="click me!" name="clicks">
</form>
    <p>Click Count: <?php echo get_user_meta('click_count', $current_user, true); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

**How to count button clicks for each users?**

Comment: Can you ellaborate a little further, you've stated what you want it to do, but you haven't described what it's currently doing. What's wrong with the code you posted? Additionally, when you say `PHP` or `HTML`, which files are these located in? Is this a theme or a plugin?

Comment: @TomJNowell Both file are in theme, First part in function.php and second in single.php. For logged in users i want to track how many times they click on this button. Actually this is a project for college students.

Comment: @TomJNowell Simple tracking and record how many times any a click this button.

Comment: Yes but what does it currently do? If it's broken, **how** is it broken? Are there error messages? Warnings? Does it work but the counter never increases? WSOD?

Comment: @TomJNowell Code not submit value to database, only From action done after submit

Comment: I think something missing in function.php part because its not put value into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The First Problem

The cause of this is not a WP problem, but a fundamental misunderstanding of how HTML forms work.

To be specific, the problem is here:

```
if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) {
```

There is no input named `clicks`, so this value is never set ( because you never set it ).

Lets look at your form:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('home')?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="click me!" name="clicks">
</form>
    <p>Click Count: <?php echo get_user_meta('click_count', $current_user, true); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Here, it submits a form to the homepage using `POST`, but it never sends any information. The only `input` tag is the submission button. A hidden input is needed with the `name` of `clicks`

### The Second Problem

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
    setcount($userID);
```

Here, the code fetches the current user, but then passes `$userID` to `setcount`. `$userID` is not defined anywhere though, it has no value, so PHP defaults it to `null` or an empty value. This is why even if you submit the form succesfully, it fails to update the database

### A Final Note

If you double click the submit button, the code will enter a race condition as multiple requests try to increment the value. Depending on how fast the server is, the server load, and how quickly the user double clicks, the count will increment, or it will increment by 2 instead of 1.

So disable the submit button after it's clicked via javascript

Comment: Not work for me when I add `<input type="hidden" value="" name="clicks">` also I try  `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_user_meta('click_count', $current_user, true); ?>" name="clicks">`